# Too many decimals in SASS/CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

Should I worry about too many decimals in my `sass/css` values?

I'm working on a web that should be scalable so I'm using `ems` and `rems` for element/font sizes.

Using sass I have a function to return font size in `em` as in em(33px) and it generates values like these 1.94118 em, which I guess is already trimmed by `sass`.

Chrome does seem to render everything perfectly but should I worry about compatibility, bugs, something breaking ?

I need to support `IE11` onwards so I guess I don't have to worry on that front.

Should I round to 2 decimal places, for example? Is it a better practice?

Comment: have you tested it on other browsers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: It's perfectly OK and cross-browser to have 5-6 digits after decimal point. It's just a regular floating-point value.